# How filter and sort array by category and date using Lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, momentjs, lodash

Hello to all I am new in this, I try sort and filter array of object using lodash, I don't know is the correct solution but I know is work, I have array some like this...

```
contactList =[    { 
      "ChatCount": 2, "chatid": 10000413, "createdon": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000", "isArchive": 0, "isOnline": false ,
      "members":[{"id": "60259166", "lastseen": 15261867,"name": "la", "picture": "/la/5285871.250.jpg"}],
      "message": "",
      "message_cnt": 1,
      "messageid": 1,
      "newest_message": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000",
      "oldest_message": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000",
      "received_cnt": 0,
      "sentby": [{"id":59,"name":"betsynray","picture":"/betsynray/2884P1010025250.jpg","lastseen":1164}],
      "unread_cnt": 1
     },
     {
         "ChatCount": 2, "chatid": 61247987, "createdon": "2018-10-25T13:49:14.9170000", "isArchive": 0,"isOnline": true,
         "members":[{"id": 61247987, "lastseen": 15318187,"name": "li", "picture": "/li/4705502.250.jpg"}],
         "message": "good",
        "message_cnt": 2,
        "messageid": 2,
        "newest_message": "2018-10-31T10:20:29.5000000",
        "oldest_message": "2018-10-25T13:47:59.6700000",
        "received_cnt": 0,
        "sentby": [{"id":59,"name":"mm","picture":"/mm/2884P1010025250.jpg","lastseen":1164}],
        "unread_cnt": 3
     }

]
```

them I want to filter (sentBy.lastseen > 18000) and sort by most recent date using (newest_message) I have lodahs and when I try for example sort by date I'm using some like this...

```
contactList.sort(function (o) { return moment(o.NEWEST_MESSAGE).format('YYYYMMDD')}).reverse();
```

This working but now I try filter also by lastseen I try something like this using lodas and momentjs

```
 function any() {

   var status = _(contactList)
        .filter(function (a) { return a.MEMBERS[0].lastseen > 1800000 }) 
        .sort(function (o) { return moment(o.NEWEST_MESSAGE).format('YYYYMMDD')}).reverse() // sort names
        .value();
        return status;

}
```

the latseen filter is work well but no the sort by recent date, What am I doing wrong someone can help me? thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 5):

can you try just to format it to a timestamp:

```
.sort(function (o) { return moment(o.newest_message).unix()})
```

And if I see it right you dont need to wrap `contactList` in a lodash function...

`filter`,`sort` and `reverse` are native array functions.

---

```
var status = contactList
        .filter(function (a) { return a.members[0].lastseen > 1800000 })
        .sort(function (o) { return moment(o.newest_message).unix() })
        .reverse();
return status;
```

Comment: I think this solve my first situation but I have other on click event for sort by recent too I use this .sort(function (o) { return moment(o.newest_message).unix()}) but is not working I try this also contactList.sort(function (o) { return moment(o.NEWEST_MESSAGE).format('YYYYMMDD')}).reverse(); and sort but wrong

Comment: I have this now .filter(function (a) { return a.MEMBERS[0].lastseen > 1800000 }) 
        .sort(function (o) { return moment(o.newest_message).unix()})
        .reverse()  but is sort the old date in the first place I think is reverse() is something different of reverse ?? for sort old in the last places and recent first one

Answer (score 3):

What you need is order by with simple `Date` object, `moment` is not at all required (however you can still use for complex date logic.

It should be just:

```
_.orderBy(contactList, o=>new Date(o.newest_message), 'desc')
```

Here is an working example:

```js
var contactList =[    { 
      "ChatCount": 2, "chatid": 10000413, "createdon": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000", "isArchive": 0, "isOnline": false ,
      "members":[{"id": "60259166", "lastseen": 15261867,"name": "la", "picture": "/la/5285871.250.jpg"}],
      "message": "",
      "message_cnt": 1,
      "messageid": 1,
      "newest_message": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000",
      "oldest_message": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000",
      "received_cnt": 0,
      "sentby": [{"id":59,"name":"betsynray","picture":"/betsynray/2884P1010025250.jpg","lastseen":1164}],
      "unread_cnt": 1
     },
     {
         "ChatCount": 2, "chatid": 61247987, "createdon": "2018-10-25T13:49:14.9170000", "isArchive": 0,"isOnline": true,
         "members":[{"id": 61247987, "lastseen": 15318187,"name": "li", "picture": "/li/4705502.250.jpg"}],
         "message": "good",
        "message_cnt": 2,
        "messageid": 2,
        "newest_message": "2018-10-31T10:20:29.5000000",
        "oldest_message": "2018-10-25T13:47:59.6700000",
        "received_cnt": 0,
        "sentby": [{"id":59,"name":"mm","picture":"/mm/2884P1010025250.jpg","lastseen":1164}],
        "unread_cnt": 3
     }

];

var st = _(contactList)
        .filter(a => a.members[0].lastseen > 1800000) 
        .orderBy(o=>new Date(o.newest_message), 'desc')
        .value();
        
console.log(st);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can use `asc` for ascending and `desc` for descending sorting (the last arg). and also you can pass any other field you need for sorting by name (in case with simple value) or you can pass a callback returning the value based on it will sort.

Answer (score 1):

Since your dates are in ISO format you don't really need anything but `orderBy` with `desc` like this:

```js
var data = [{ "ChatCount": 2, "chatid": 10000413, "createdon": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000", "isArchive": 0, "isOnline": false, "members": [{ "id": "60259166", "lastseen": 15261867, "name": "la", "picture": "/la/5285871.250.jpg" }], "message": "", "message_cnt": 1, "messageid": 1, "newest_message": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000", "oldest_message": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000", "received_cnt": 0, "sentby": [{ "id": 59, "name": "betsynray", "picture": "/betsynray/2884P1010025250.jpg", "lastseen": 1164 }], "unread_cnt": 1 }, { "ChatCount": 2, "chatid": 61247987, "createdon": "2018-10-25T13:49:14.9170000", "isArchive": 0, "isOnline": true, "members": [{ "id": 61247987, "lastseen": 15318187, "name": "li", "picture": "/li/4705502.250.jpg" }], "message": "good", "message_cnt": 2, "messageid": 2, "newest_message": "2018-10-31T10:20:29.5000000", "oldest_message": "2018-10-25T13:47:59.6700000", "received_cnt": 0, "sentby": [{ "id": 59, "name": "mm", "picture": "/mm/2884P1010025250.jpg", "lastseen": 1164 }], "unread_cnt": 3 } ];

var result = _(data)
  .filter(x => _.get(x, 'members.0.lastseen') > 1800000)
  .orderBy('newest_message', 'desc')
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```